# Watir - Error when I try to take screenshot of div

Tags: ruby, watir

I use Watir and Watir-element-screenshot to get screenshot of elements. 
Browser: Chrome and Firefox (latest versions) 
My code:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir/extensions/element/screenshot'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'google.com.ua'    
browser.text_field(id: "lst-ib").set "ruby\n"    
browser.window.maximize
browser.element(id: "resultStats").screenshot("2.png")   
browser.close
```

And take this error:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/color.rb:968:in `scanline_bytesize': undefined method `>>' for 2439.0:Float (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  >
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:207:in `encode_png_image_pass_to_stream'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:174:in `encode_png_image_without_interlacing'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:161:in `encode_png_pixelstream'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:85:in `to_datastream'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/image.rb:62:in `to_datastream'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:35:in `write'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:43:in `block in save'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:43:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.8/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb:43:in `save'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-extensions-element-screenshot-0.0.3/lib/watir/extensions/element/screenshot.rb:12:in `screenshot'
    from 2.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

What the reason of this message and how can i repair it?

Comment: Screenshot is coming properly, but what I found a problem in your code is that the given id `resultStats` doesn't exist in the specified page, I used this id `sb_ifc0` which is an id of a division

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to take screen shot and save in specific location.

```
 browser.screenshot.save("path to save image/2.png")
```